# can someone explain to me what the right side of this line of code means?

Tags: c, linux, file, system

```
fcbArray[i].fi = (fileInfo *)-2; 

typedef struct b_fcb
    {
    fileInfo * fi;  

    } b_fcb;
```

not sure what "fileInfo *" is in the parentheses or the -2

Comment: As any decent text-book, class or tutorial should have taught you, it's a *type cast*. It tells the compiler to treat a value of one type as a value of another type. For this specific example, it tells the compiler to treat the `int` value `-2` as a `fileInfo` pointer.

Comment: `(fileInfo *)` is a type casting operation. that means that the integer  `-2` should be seen as  a pointer of type fileInfo.

Comment: You either do not know what a pointer is or haven't read about type casting — how did you end on this piece of code? Just curious.

Comment: To clarify the above, the integer value -2 is being *explicitly converted* to a value of type `fileInfo *`. The conversion is implementation-defined. It is unllikely to point to something valid, but sometimes such tricks with special pointer values are used for special purposes such as encoding errors.

Answer (score 2):

`(fileInfo *) -2` casts the value `-2` to a `fileInfo` pointer (which is a typedef not shown).  A pointer is usually an address or NULL, and rarely an explicit value like here as it may represent a valid address.